# Portability of an mobile application from Windows Mobile 5.0 to Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, portability, windows-mobile-5.0

My customer has an existing application on Windows Mobile 5.0. He wants to have the same application working on Windows Mobile 6.5. I don't have a Windows Mobile 6.5 device on my hands, so I can't do these tests myself.

I want to know if :

- Is it possible to transfer on WM6.5 only the bin compiled for WM5.0 without modifications or we have to recompile it ?
- Is it possible to have the same bin for WM6.5 and WM5.0 or we have to compile 2 differents bin ?
- The screen of the WM6.5 device is 2x greater in size, I want to know how the program will be rendered. Is the program will stuck in the top on the corner of the screen or will be zoomed to fit in the screen ?

Thank you

Comment: You can install the Windows Mobile 6.5 developer toolkit which comes with an emulator, so you can run your app on there for some testing without an actual device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The app will move to the new platform without recompiling.  You can go "backward" only if apps don't use APIs specific to the newer platform, but forward is not a problem.
- How it will be rendered will depend on how your app sets up things like auto-scaling and if it has code to resize/move things (like Dock and Anchor in managed code).  Run it on a WinMo 6.5 emulator and see what shakes out.